# Codeigniter Updating database data from a select dropdown

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to update database names from a select dropdown.

This is what I have so far:

view (exammenu_view.php)

```
<form name='selectexam' action="<?php echo base_url() . "index.php/exam/select/";?>" method='post'>   
<div class="form-group">
   <select class="form-control" name="exam_id">
    <?php 
    foreach($exams as $row)
    { 
      echo '<option value="'.$row->exam_id.'">'.$row->examname.'</option>';
    }
    ?>
    </select>
</div>
    <label>Examen wijzigen</label>
    <div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="update" class="form-control" placeholder="Examennaam"></div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" name="sbm" value="Wijzigen" class="btn btn-info" />
    <input type="submit" name="sbm" value="Verwijderen" class="btn btn-info" />
</div>
</form>
```

controller (exam.php)

```
function select() {
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    if($this->input->post('sbm') == 'Verwijderen') { 
        $exam_id = $_POST['exam_id'];   
        $this->exam_model->removeExam($exam_id);

        if(!empty($exam_id)){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('del','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Examen verwijderd.</div>'); }
        elseif(empty($exam_id)){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('del','<div class="alert alert-warning text-center">Er zijn geen examens gevonden om te verwijderen.</div>');  
        }
        redirect('/exam/');
    }

        elseif($this->input->post('sbm') == "Wijzigen") {
            $data = $this->input->post('dname');
            $this->exam_model->editExam($data);
            $this->getExamName();
        }
    }
}
```

model (exam_model.php)

```
function getExamName(){
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT exam_id, examname FROM exam');
    return $query->result();
}  

function removeExam($id){
    $this->db->where('exam_id', $id);
    $this->db->delete('exam');
} 

function editExam($id){
    $this->db->where('exam_id', $id);
    $this->db->update('exam', $id);
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
A Database Error Occurred
You must use the "set" method to update an entry.
Filename: models/Exam_model.php
```

I've tried lots of things but i can't figure it out how i can get it to work properly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `$this->db->update('exam', $id);`?? what you are trying to update?

Comment: @shaiful-islam I want to get the exam name from the select dropdown and replace that exam name in the form below and post that info with the button "Wijzigen" which means change in Dutch.

Answer (score 0):

The error you see stems from an incorrectly formatted variable being passed to update the table. In the editExam model function the $id variable is passed to update the column but it does not contain an array format.

You can use:

```
$data2 = array('table_column_name' => 'dname');
```

then pass it to the function

```
function editExam($id, $data2){
    $this->db->where('exam_id', $id);
    $this->db->update('exam', $data2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately it doesn't work. I'm getting this errors

Missing argument 2 for Exam_model::editExam()
Filename: models/Exam_model.php

Message: Array to string conversion
Filename: database/DB_query_builder.php

Message: Undefined variable: data
Filename: models/Exam_model.php

You must use the "set" method to update an entry.
Filename: models/Exam_model.php

Comment: Which method in the Model is being executed from your test?

Comment: You mean the actual exam test or what i've just tested? I'm kinda new to programming and PHP

Comment: If it says that it is missing argument 2 in the editExam() function then you are missing the $data parameter in the header of the function. Double check the amount of parameters you are passing and match that amount in the function header. I re-edited my post since you already used $data in your controller. And for the test, i wanted to know what test case you were executing so i can properly trace through the code.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It did help me. I reordered my code and I fixed it. I'll post an answer below

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 $data = $this->input->post('dname');
 $this->exam_model->editExam($data);
```

to

```
$data = $this->input->post('update');
$this->exam_model->editExam($data,$exam_id);
```

then change the editExam function

```
function editExam($exam_id, $data)
{
    $this->db->where('exam_id', $exam_id);
    $this->db->update('exam', $data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It gives me these errors: Message: Undefined variable: exam_id (in the controller) and You must use the "set" method to update an entry (in the model)

Answer (score 0):

View

```
<form name='selectexam' action="<?php echo base_url() . "index.php/exam/select/";?>" method='post'>   
    <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" name="exam_id">
        <?php 
        foreach($exams as $row)
        { 
        echo '<option value="'.$row->exam_id.'">'.$row->examname.'</option>';
        }
        ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <label>Examen wijzigen</label>
    <div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="update" class="form-control" placeholder="Examennaam"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" name="sbm" value="Wijzigen" class="btn btn-info" />
        <input type="submit" name="sbm" value="Verwijderen" class="btn btn-info" />
</div>
</form>
```

Controller

```
function select() {
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
if($this->input->post('sbm') == 'Verwijderen') { 
    $exam_id = $_POST['exam_id'];   
    $this->exam_model->removeExam($exam_id);

    if(!empty($exam_id)){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('del','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Examen verwijderd.</div>'); }
    elseif(empty($exam_id)){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('del','<div class="alert alert-warning text-center">Er zijn geen examens gevonden om te verwijderen.</div>');  
    }
    redirect('/exam/');
}

    elseif($this->input->post('sbm') == "Wijzigen") {
        $data2 = array(
            'examname' => $this->input->post ('update'),
        );
        $id = $_POST['exam_id'];
        $this->exam_model->editExam($id, $data2);
        $this->exam_model->getExamName();
    }
    redirect('/exam/');
    }
}
```

Model

```
function getExamName(){
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT exam_id, examname FROM exam');
    return $query->result();
}  

function removeExam($id){
    $this->db->where('exam_id', $id);
    $this->db->delete('exam');
} 

function editExam($id, $data2){
    $this->db->where('exam_id', $id);
    $this->db->update('exam', $data2);
}
```